# When exactly can I put a bounty on my unanswered meta question?

Tags: support, bounties, meta, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I've never used the bounty system and have a question on the meta Japanese L & U beta site I'd like to try it out on:

> [What to do with the "words" and "vocabulary" tags?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200/what-to-do-with-the-words-and-vocabulary-tags)

But there is no link or button to add a bounty like I have seen elsewhere when I wasn't interested in them, and none appears when I edit the question either.

What must I do? Wait a certain time? Wait for some kind of event to occur? Or are bounties only applicable to the main sites and not the meta sites?

Comment: It's not two days yet

Comment: @random: Hmm then should I report this as a bug? "edited 2 days ago asked 2 days ago"

Comment: No need. You can't place bounties on child meta sites. Only Meta Stack Overflow. Every other meta you don't actually have rep to give bounty from.